# Enable visitors to see last published version during OOTB approval workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, approval

How to enable visitors to see last published version during OOTB approval workflow if the Draft Item Security is set to Only Users Who can approve it. Currently no visitors are able to see the page until the approval workflow complete.

Answer (score 3):

The scenario happens if you have no version 1.0 approved and published. If you have a version 1.0 approved and published, and a version 1.1 in approval workflow, users with at least read permission should be able to view the published 1.0 version.

If read access users get Access Denied browsing the published page, one could try deactivating and reactivating two Site Collection features: Workflows and Publishing Approval Workflow.

Comment: I have last major version published 3.0. Also major and minor version enabled. content approval is also enabled. when page get into the approval workflow visitors are not able to see the last major version published. They see error Sorry this Item is not shared with you.

Comment: @VikasSharma What does the ULS log say when user with read permission hit the page? Access denied or page not found?

Comment: They get Access Denied

Comment: I deactivated workflows as well as publishing approval features, and activated again but no luck..

Comment: @VikasSharma That's strange. In these cases I usually go the long way: 1) Create a new Web Application, 2) Site Collection, 3) Activate features 4) set up library settings 5) create workflow and try again. But it takes a while unfortunately. What version and build of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: This is SharePoint 2013 On premise environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33267/discussion-between-benny-skogberg-and-vikas-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

It was my own mistake, I had the status of approved on each approval task process. I later changed it to Pending and this resolved my issue.